# Can't disable swap on a GPT-based system

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, swap, gpt

I want to disable swap on several running ubuntu 16.04 servers. I'd like, if possible, not to reboot them. From my research, it seemed that

- running `swapoff -a` to disable swap until the next reboot
- and commenting the swap line in `/etc/fstab` to persist after the next reboot

should do the job. However, it seems that the kernel is re-enabling the swap: a varying amount of time after the `swapoff`, I see something like that in the `/var/log/kern.log` log:

`Nov 28 12:00:51 srv07 kernel: [ 8049.183480] Adding 62498812k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:62498812k FS`

Once I had it happen 4 hours after the `swapoff`, another time 5 minutes.

What's causing this?

This is on Ubuntu 16.04 server, kernel version 4.4.0.

Comment: Is that all the information related to the adding of the swap device in the logs? You might want to check systemd's journal too.

Comment: See my answer, the culprit was GPT's auto-mounting feature.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Nico!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disks were using GPT, and this was due to [GPT partition automounting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#GPT_partition_automounting):

> On a GPT partitioned disk systemd-gpt-auto-generator(8) will mount partitions following the Discoverable Partitions Specification, thus they can be omitted from fstab.

[Another page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GPT_fdisk#Prevent_GPT_partition_automounting) of the same documentation explains how to disable this:

> Start gdisk, e.g.:
>
> $ gdisk /dev/sda
>
> Press p to print the partition table and take note of the partition
>   number(s) of the for which you want to disable automounting.
>
> Press x extra functionality (experts only).
>
> Press a set attributes. Input the partition number and set the
>   attribute 63. Under Set fields are: it should now show 63 (do not
>   automount). Press Enter to end attribute changing. Repeat this for all
>   partitions you want to prevent from automounting.
>
> When done write the table to disk and exit via the w command.
>
> Alternatively using sgdisk, the attribute can be set using the
>   -A/--attributes= option; see sgdisk(8) for usage. For example, to set partition attribute 63 "do not automount" on /dev/sda2 run:
>
> $ sgdisk -A 2:set:63 /dev/sda