# Disabling Swap on Debian Permanently

Tags: debian, fstab, swap

Every guide presents disabling swap permanently as simply commenting out the corresponding line in `/etc/fstab` to prevent swap from mounting on reboot; however, that does not work in Debian 11.

Example:

`sudo swapoff -a` works perfectly, but doesn't persist across reboots.

Example fstab File, with line commented out:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# systemd generates mount units based on this file, see systemd.mount(5).
# Please run 'systemctl daemon-reload' after making changes here.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6b762cb8-b92b-489a-98cf-2bf200e3c4ae /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4847-3887  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
# UUID=b9aeb506-ad7d-488d-b2b9-7c68dff21906 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

**Manual**

After turning off swap manually:

`sudo swapoff -a`

`lsblk`

the Swap Partition is still mounted but is no longer listed as a swap partition.  Swap is successfully disabled:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   127G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 125.5G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0   976M  0 part
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

**Editing Fstab**

After editing fstab file, running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and performing a system reboot, swap is still there

`lsblk -o +PARTTYPE`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT PARTTYPE
sda      8:0    0   127G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi  c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
├─sda2   8:2    0 125.5G  0 part /          0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
└─sda3   8:3    0   976M  0 part [SWAP]     0657fd6d-a4ab-43c4-84e5-0933c84b4f4f
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Clearly there's still a step missing.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `lsblk -o +PARTTYPE` instead of plain `lsblk`?

Comment: @StephenKitt testing in a debian 11 the swap parttype is different to the one in fstab, following OP's process.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes, that’s normal, the `fstab` lists the partition UUID, not the type UUID, and it’s the latter I’m interested in (because it’s what the systemd generator uses).

Answer (score 11):

It is activated by systemd. See `man systemd-fstab-generator` and `man systemd.swap`.

Archlinux wiki: [Activation by systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/swap#Activation_by_systemd)

> **systemd** activates swap partitions based on two different mechanisms. Both are executables in /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators. The generators are run on start-up and create native systemd units for mounts. The first, systemd-fstab-generator, reads the fstab to generate units, including a unit for swap. The second, systemd-gpt-auto-generator inspects the root disk to generate units. It operates on GPT disks only, and can identify swap partitions by their type GUID, see [systemd#GPT partition automounting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd#GPT_partition_automounting) for more information.

[Disabling swap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/swap#Disabling_swap)

> To deactivate specific swap space:

```
# swapoff /dev/sdxy
```

> Alternatively use the -a switch to deactivate all swap space.

> **Since swap is managed by systemd, it will be activated again on the next system startup**. To disable the automatic activation of detected swap space permanently, run `systemctl --type swap` to find the responsible `.swap` unit **and mask it**.

Check the status:

```
systemctl status *swap
```

or :

```
systemctl --type swap
```

Then disable the service:

```
sudo systemctl mask  "dev-*.swap"
```

Comment: Can you expand on why this would add swap when not configured to do so.  Disabling the systemd unit which adds swap by configuration seems overkill otherwise.

Comment: @PhilipCouling See my edit with some documentations.

Comment: This methodology of masking the `systemctl` service made the most sense to me and was effective. -- I am curious if this is the best way to do it though.

Comment: should be marked as the answer. Works very well in debian 11

Comment: The answer is too complex. The exact `.swap` unit is required at the `sudo systemctl mask  "dev-*.swap"`, and the unit name is known only after a reboot. I have a better solution: changing swap mount options to `noauto` so that both `systemd-fstab-generator` and `systemd-gpt-auto-generator` ignore this swap device.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  When I ran 'systemctl --type *swap', it returned me a unit name of 'var-swap.swap'.  Masking that and rebooting still resulted in swap being mounted (in the swap file /var/swap).

Answer (score 3):

systemd is by default in automatic mode and does not need fstab to get active:

> **systemd-gpt-auto-generator** is a unit generator that
> automatically discovers root, /home/, /srv/, /var/, /var/tmp/, the EFI
> System Partition,
> the Extended Boot Loader Partition **and swap partitions**

This generator can be masked in a separate admin override dir:

```
/etc/systemd/system-generators/systemd-gpt-auto-generator -> /dev/null
```

`systemd.gpt_auto=no` as boot param should have the same effect.

The man page continues:

> systemd-gpt-auto-generator is useful for centralizing file system
> configuration in the partition table and making configuration in
> **/etc/fstab** or on the kernel command line **unnecessary**.

`fstab-generator` comes second/can override. But since you did comment swap out, I guess gpt-auto is turning it on.

The `sda3` is not *still mounted*. `lsblk` works like `fdisk -l` at partition level. `[SWAP]` entry is like a mountpoint.

Try `swapon --show` because there can be also swap files and several swaps.

Comment: Here is a similar, self-answered Q: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554601/cant-disable-swap-on-a-gpt-based-system. With a special kind of solution.

Comment: Results of `swapon --show`
`/dev/sda3 partition 976M   0B   -2`

Comment: In this answer, where would I mark `systemd.gpt_auto=no` in the system?

Comment: That would be a kernel boot parameter. You could add it to `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub` for persistent use, or press `e` in GRUB boot menu and add it to the `linux...` line for one-time use.

Answer (score 0):

You need change [vm.swappiness](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#swappiness) linux kernel parameter and make changes permanently in **/etc/sysctl.conf** file. And reboot system.

The default value of **vm.swappiness** is **60** and **represents the percentage of the free memory before activating swap**. The lower the value, the less swapping is used and the more memory pages are kept in physical memory.

For disable swap permanently on your debian system:

- edit **/etc/sysctl.conf file** file and add to end of file if not present **vm.swappiness = 0**
- reboot system

```bash
# edit /etc/sysctl.conf file
~] vi /etc/sysctl.conf 

# disable swap
# add to end of file if not present:
vm.swappiness = 0

# reboot for changes
~] systemctl reboot
```

Here is guide [how disable swap on linux permanently](https://www.mybluelinux.com/how-disable-swap-in-debian-or-linux-system/).

Comment: No, this isn't the right solution. I used to work in mission critical telecoms and we investigated this, swappiness does very little actually. The tl;dr it doesn't do what people think it does.

Comment: I work for telecom with mission critical system too. And this soulution with kernel parameters work perfectly. This disable swap in kernel directly!!! But delete swap partition is the best solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

GAD3R's answer is too complicated.
The exact .swap unit is required at the `sudo systemctl mask  "dev-*.swap"`, and the unit name is known only after a reboot.
I have a better solution: changing swap mount options to noauto so that both systemd-fstab-generator and systemd-gpt-auto-generator ignore this swap device.

Answer (score 0):

The missed step might be running `sudo update-initramfs -u` after changing `/etc/fstab`, to make sure that also the copy of `fstab` within the initramfs file is up to date.

Otherwise, the swap might be activated very early in the boot process, when the system is still running on initramfs. If that happens, there is no step in the boot process that would later deactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on a raspberry pi running Ubuntu 11:

Disable the dphys-swapfile.service, by running:

```
$ sudo swapoff -a
$ sudo systemctl stop dphys-swapfile
$ sudo dphys-swapfile uninstall
$ sudo systemctl mask dphys-swapfile
```

then reboot, and the auto-generated swap file in /var/swap should be gone, and no swap should be active.  Note that the
command 'dphys-swapfile uninstall' does not uninstall the dphys-swapfile system.  It is there to remove /var/swap, which on my system was 100M in size.