# Why k3s is still seeing swap on Debian Bullseye?

Tags: debian, swap, kubernetes

I've installed [k3s](https://k3s.io/) on Debian Bullseye (on M1 Pro through qemu/[UTM](https://github.com/utmapp/UTM)).

k3s recommend to disable the swap. After reading the answers of the following questions:

- [How to safely turn off swap permanently and reclaim the space? (on Debian Jessie)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224156/how-to-safely-turn-off-swap-permanently-and-reclaim-the-space-on-debian-jessie/224348#224348)
- [Disabling Swap on Debian Permanently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671940/disabling-swap-on-debian-permanently)

I've :

- Disabled systemd swap service `sudo systemctl mask  "dev-*.swap"`
- Removed the swap partition in `/etc/fstab`.
- Deleted the swap partition and extend the main partition to regain space
- Set the swapiness to 0 in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Now I have:

```
root@debian:~# systemctl --type swap --all
  UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION
0 loaded units listed.

root@debian:~# sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 0

root@debian:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
vda    254:0    0   10G  0 disk 
├─vda1 254:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─vda2 254:2    0  9.5G  0 part /

root@debian:~# free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         1000692      705588       34164        1704      260940      221484
Swap:              0           0           0

root@debian:~# swapon -s
root@debian:~#
```

But when I run `k3s check-config`, I still have:

```
- swap: should be disabled
```

What should I do in order to fully disable the swap in the eyes of k3s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swap activation probably happens early in the boot process while the system is still running on initramfs, so after removing the swap configuration items, you should have done a `update-initramfs -u`.

I also don't see a `systemctl stop "dev-*.swap"` or `swapoff -a` anywhere: those would have been the commands to actually disable already-activated swap areas. `systemctl mask` will certainly prevent the swap units from starting, but it does nothing at all to swap areas that have already been activated. You should ensure any units you are `systemctl mask`ing are stopped first.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the Debian Bullseye VM multiple times but this was not enough. For whatever reasons, I had to stop and restart [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/). After that [k3s](https://k3s.io/) was seeing that the swap was removed.